# How to install everything on sources.list?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I made a really stupid autoremove mistake. I was uninstalling `libssl1.0.0` and it somehow said that pretty much every package I had was now not needed. I didn't really read carefully and I uninstalled a LOT of packages. I saw things like wget and node being uninstalled.

My question is, how do you install everything from sources.list, and would it be plausible to install everything from sources.list to recover from this accident?

Comment: see the file `/var/log/apt/history.log` .. you will find the list of uninstalled packages

Comment: By "install everything from sources.list" if you mean install every package in every repository you have added to `sources.list`, that is neither plausible nor possible. Plenty of packages conflict with each other, so it's not possible to have them installed at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
I just had to do `apt install ubuntu-desktop`.

I looked over the `history.log` and it seems like only default Ubuntu packages were uninstalled by the autoremove.

I don't know if this happened because of my prior installation of openSUSE Tumbleweed or not.